# $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_2$

Tags: irreducible-polynomials, cyclotomic-polynomials

I have a slight confusion about this argument below. Why did we need to show that there is no $\alpha\in \mathbb{F}_{2^2}^{\times}$ instead of $\mathbb{F}_{2}^{\times}$ in order to conclude?

We use the 5th cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_5(x)=\frac{x^5-1}{x-1}=x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$. Let $\mu_5$ denote the 5th roots of unity. It is enough to show that there are no linear factors or degree 2 factors. So we start by showing that there are no linear factors.

See that if there is an $\alpha\in \mathbb{F}_2$ such that $\alpha^5=1, \alpha^n\neq 1$ for $1\leq n\leq 4$, then $\alpha$ is a root of $\Phi_5(x)$. We also note that $\alpha$ is a unit in $\mathbb{F}_2$ because we can define $\alpha^{-1}=\alpha^4$. As a corollary of Lagrange's theorem, we know that for any $\alpha\in \mu_5$, $|\alpha|=5$ does not divide the size of the set of units $|\mathbb{F}_2^{\times}|=1$. This means $\alpha\notin \mathbb{F}_2^{\times}$ and there is no linear factor for $\Phi_5(x)$.

Now we do a similar argument to show that there is no quadratic factor.

If $\Phi_5(x)$ has a quadratic factor, then its root would come from  $\mathbb{F}_{2^2}^{\times}$. (why is this?) But we notice that for every element $\alpha \in \mu_5$, $|\alpha|=5$ and $|\mathbb{F}_{2^2}^{\times}|=3$. $5$ doesn't divide $3$, which implies that no 5th root of unity is in $\mathbb{F}_{2^2}^{\times}$. Therefore, there are no quadratic factor either and $\Phi_5(x)$ is irreducible.

Comment: Not following.  It's obvious that there are no linear factors, right?  Just try $0$ and $1$ as roots.  If your question concerns the non-existence of quadratic factors, you should include that argument.

Comment: I prefer to simply show that $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ is relatively prime to $x^4-x.$ But you need some possibly additional knowledge to know that this proves $\Phi_5(x)$ is prime.

Comment: @lulu, thank you. I edited the original post!

Comment: But in that case we are trying to rule out quadratic factors.  If there were a quadratic factor, $q(x)$, then adjoining a root of $q(x)$ would give us a quadratic extension of $\mathbb F_2$, and as the argument points out, that extension can't contain  a  non-trivial fifth root of unity either .

Comment: For goodness sake, there are only four quadratic polynomials over $\mathbb{F}_2$, and only one is irreducible and its square is clearly not this quartic.

Comment: Proving that the polynomial has no zeros in $\Bbb{F}_4\setminus\Bbb{F}_2$ is equivalent to proving that the polynomial has no quadratic factors (not degree 3, as you mistakenly wrote). Anyway, if a quartic polynomial is not irreducible, it must have a linear or a quadratic factor, so at that point you are done already.

Comment: An irreducible quadratic factor's roots have degree two, so they exist in an field extension of degree two, and the only field extension of degree two of $\Bbb F_2$ (relative to a fixed algebraic closure) is $\Bbb F_{2^2}$.

Comment: @runway44, thank you for addressing my question! That makes a lot more sense now.